# Node.js - What is the most robust way of handling an external module which may freeze the request and the server?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, minify

I am using Node.js along with Express 3.

One of my routes **receives some JSON** as a POST parameter. I **stringify that JSON in an EJS template**, inside a variable in a script tag. This way, this JSON is passed directly as a JS object in client's JavaScript.

I have been escaping/replacing that JSON as much as possible in order to avoid invalid characters. But there are still some cases where I receive something in that JSON which makes the **rendered EJS template invalid**. Here is a short exemple :

```
--EJS template
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var injectedJSON = <%- JSON.stringify(jsonToInject) %>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the received JSON contains a closing script tag for instance, it will break the rendered HTML.
That would be OK if I was directly sending this HTML to the client. That client would receive a broken HTML but it wouldn't be any worse.

The problem is that, once the HTML is rendered by EJS, i use html-minifier module to minify it. And if the html passed to html-minifier is incorrect, the **request would simply freeze**. No error throwing, no nothing, it will freeze the whole server, so all clients requests are blocked. I added a try catch to handle that but html-minifier doesn't throw any error. It just freezes :

```
function handleRequest(jsonToInject, callback){

//Render and minify
var success = true; 
try{
    console.log("trying to compile");
    var rendered = ejs.render(template, {jsonToInject:jsonToInject});
    console.log("render ok. minifying...");
    rendered = htmlminifier.minify(rendered, {
     removeComments: true,
     removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
     collapseWhitespace: true,
     collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
     removeAttributeQuotes: true,
     removeEmptyAttributes: true
    });

    //where it will freeze if html is invalid

    console.log("Minify ok. Responding with rendered html...");
    callback(false, rendered);
} catch(e){
    success = false;
    console.log("compilation/minification failed");
}

//Compile+Minification went fine. Continue to file save
if(success){
    cb(false, compiled);
}
//There was a compiling/minify problem. Send serror
else {
    callback(true, "Failed compilation or minification for app.");
}
}
```

In the above case, if the rendered HTML is invalid, htmlminifier won't throw any error, it will just freeze. So **it will never enter the catch statement, nor continue** to the if(success) statement.

For that closing script case, I added some string replacement so it is fixed. What I want is finding a way to make sure this minify won't freeze my server. I cannot find anything apart adding from a timeout to the request.

Comment: The 'easy' answer is: Don't use that module. You should never use a module that just freezes up your entire server - that's a sure sign of horrible logic/code. The [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues) are usually not answered/fixed, but answered with 'this HTML is valid'... There's other minifier modules for node out there, e.g. [Minify](http://coderaiser.github.io/minify/).

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that the module shoudl'nt behave this way. Which is indeed a bad thing because it is the most used module for minification https://www.npmjs.org/package/html-minifier . Of course I will change that module, but the point of the question was more "how to build a robust error handling for this kind of behaviors"

Comment: Alright, I'll try to help you with that then. Could you clarify what you mean exactly by 'adding a timeout to the request' / add that to your answer? There's multiple ways I can imagine, and I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well I was thinking about setting something like the timeout parameter on connect's request https://github.com/expressjs/timeout

Comment: Could you try out what happens if you place the code inside the try block inside a `process.nextTick(...)` instead? You'll need to remove the catch block for that, but it's just for testing. I wasn't able to reproduce `html-minifier` hanging up with intentionally broken input.